# How do you save one line into a linkedlist and next line into another list when reading from file

Tags: java, split, linked-list, bufferedreader, filereader

I want to read from a file and store every line into a separate `LinkedList` but I don't know how to do it since I'm using the split function.

The text is something like this:

```
124,53,7,2

1,2,34,567,23
```

So store the first line into a `LinkedList` and the second line into another `LinkedList`.

ex:num1 holds 124, 53, 7, 2 nodes
   num2 holds 1, 2, 34, 567, 23 nodes

```
if(args.length == 0)
    System.out.println("No file specified.");
else{
    FileReader theFile;
    BufferedReader inFile;
    String oneLine;
    int s;

    try{
        theFile = new FileReader(args[0]);
        inFile = new BufferedReader(theFile);
        LargeNumber num1 = new LargeNumber();
        LargeNumber num2 = new LargeNumber();
        while((oneLine = inFile.readLine()) != null){
            String numbers[] = oneLine.split(",");
            s = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
                num1.push(Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]));
            }
            if((inFile.readLine()).length()==0){
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe `numbers[i]` instead of `numbers[0]` ?

Comment: Ok hope the edit helps clarify my question and Antonio I actually meant that just forgot it. Thanks for your comments guys

Comment: It sounds like you have not fully described your problem statement from your comment on my answer and on joey's answer. Can you please [edit] your question to clarify exactly what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, it seems that you want to arrange your lists in pairs. This is the easiest way to do that, but not necessarily the best:

```
List<LargeNumber> firstList = new ArrayList<>();
List<LargeNumber> secondList = new ArrayList<>();
try{
    theFile = new FileReader(args[0]);
    inFile = new BufferedReader(theFile);
    while(inFile.ready()){
        String firstLine = getNonEmptyLine(inFile);
        if(firstLine.isEmpty()) break;
        String secondLine = getNonEmptyLine(inFile);
        if(secondLine.isEmpty()) break;
        firstList.add(makeLargeNumber(firstLine));
        secondList.add(makeLargeNumber(secondLine));
    }
}
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Here's the `readNonEmptyLine()` method:

```
private String readNonEmptyLine(BufferedReader reader) {
     while(reader.ready()) {
          String nextLine = reader.readLine();
          if(!nextLine.isEmpty()) return nextLine;
     }
     return "";
}
```

And here's the `makeLargeNumber` method:

```
private LargeNumber makeLargeNumber(String line) {
    LargeNumber num1 = new LargeNumber();
    String numbers[] = oneLine.split(",");
    s = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        num1.push(Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]));
    }
    return num1;
}
```

This will work, but it would be even better to have a class like this:

```
class NumberPair {
    LargeNumber firstNumber;
    LargeNumber secondNumber;
}
```

And then only have one `List` instead of two. I think you can figure out how to modify the above code to use the `NumberPair` class.

Comment: Isn't this going to add a linked list of all the numbers separated by "," and store them all into "list"? which does not answer my question. If i'm wrong then sorry i'm still a rookie.

Comment: It's going to create as many `LargeNumber` instances as you have lines in the file. It's a **list of lists**. Think about it like a notepad of grocery lists, where each page is it's own list, and then the entire pad is the "outer" list. Try it for yourself! Override the `toString()` method in your `LargeNumber` class to display the contents, then `System.out.println()` the `List<LargeNumber>`

Comment: I see how your code would work but the reason why i wanted  separated names was so I would apply mathematical operation between 2 linkedlists. @joeyrohan

Comment: Thanks a lot @durron597

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `List<LargeNumber>` instead of num1, num2, num3, and so on.

so it would look something like this:

```
List<LargeNumber> myNumbers = new ArrayList();
try ( ... ) {
    String line;
    while((line = ...readLine()) != null) {
        LargeNumber number = new LargeNumber();
        for(part : line.split(...)){
            number.push(Integer.parseInt(part));
        }
        myNumbers.add(number);
    }
}
```

If you want to only have n number of numbers (n=2, num1 and num2 for example) and you want to alternate between the two, use an array instead.

```
LargeNumber[] myNumbers = new LargeNumber[n];
for(int i = 0; i < myNumbers.length; i++) myNumbers[i] = new LargeNumber();
try ( ... ) {
    String line;
    int i = 0;
    while((line = ...readLine()) != null) {
        LargeNumber number = myNumbers[i%myNumbers.length];
        for(part : line.split(...)){
            number.push(Integer.parseInt(part));
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

and don't forget to close your readers! (just use [try-with-resouces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) :) )

Answer (score 1):

If you know the number of lines already, you can create an array of lists where the size of the array is the number of lines. You would then use the line number to determine what list to use.

If you dont know how many lines there will be, create a list of lists.

My example assumes you dont know how many lines there will be.

```
List<LinkedList<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>();

//BufferedReader stuff...

int lineNum = 0;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    try
    {
        LinkedList<Integer> numbers = new LinkedList();
        String[] components = line.split(",");
        for (String s : components)
        {
            numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
        }
        lineNum++;
        lists.add(numbers);
    } catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("An error has occured: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you know the number of lines already? Also, he probably has to use his `LargeNumber` class

Comment: Just change `Integer` in the linkedlist to `LargeNumber` then :)

Comment: Oops, I just realised `lineNum++;` was inside the for loop... that shouldn't be the case. Fixed in edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your class objects into any suitable collection.Eg

```
 List<LargeNumber> list=new ArrayList<LargeNumber>;
```

Add your objects:

```
list.add(num);
```

You can get the values by using a for-each loop:

```
for(LargeNumber l:list)
  l.method()//...
```

Comment: What if there are more than 2 numbers?

Comment: This answer is to a specific user problem.OP only mentioned 2 list @durron597

Comment: He said "store every line"; the two lines were just an example.

Comment: Yes thanks @durron597 is correct. I have many lines of numbers with space after every two lines, so I have to read two lines at a time and store each line into a separate linkedlist